# PHP Group & add elements in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
[type] =>
[base] => 10.0
[amount] => 0
)
[1] => Array(
[type] => 15.0
[base] => 12.0
[amount] => 1.8
)
[2] => Array(
[type] => 15.0
[base] => 12.0
[amount] => 1.8
)
[3] => Array(
[type] => 2.0
[base] => 12.0
[amount] => 0.24
)
```

How can I get below  array with php? I need to group "types" adding "amount" & "amount", but omitting elements without type value

```
Array(
[0] => Array(
[type] => 15.0
[base] => 24.0
[amount] => 3.6
)
[1] => Array(
[type] => 2.0
[base] => 12.0
[amount] => 0.24
)
)
```

Comment: Are you really grouping or are you just tying to omit them? For example what happens if you have more than one array with the same `type` value but different `amount` values?

Answer (score 1):

[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) comes to the rescue:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function($memo, $item) {
    if (!isset($item['type'])) return $memo;
    if (!isset($memo['' . $item['type']])) { // first occurence
      $memo['' . $item['type']] = $item;
    } else {                                 // will sum
      $memo['' . $item['type']]['base'] += $item['base'];
      $memo['' . $item['type']]['amount'] += $item['amount'];
    }
    return $memo;
 }, array());

 var_dump(array_values($result));
```